# problems with char array = char array

Tags: c, arrays, char

I have:

```
char message1[100];
char message2[100];
```

When I try to do `message1 = message2`, I get error:

> incompatible types when assigning to type `‘char[100]’` from type `‘char *’`

I have functions like

```
if(send(clntSocket, echoBuffer, recvMsgSize, 0) != recvMsgSize){
   DieWithError("send() failed")
}
```

inbetween.  Could these mess things up somehow? :(

I have a feeling maybe you can't do `=` on char arrays or something, but I looked around and couldn't find anything.

Comment: are you using the C++ compiler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your suspicions are correct.  C (I'm assuming this is C) treats an array variable as a pointer.

You need to read the C FAQ about arrays and pointers: http://c-faq.com/aryptr/index.html

Comment: More precisely, an expression of array type (such as the name of an array variable) is implicitly converted, in *most* contexts, to a pointer to the first element of the array object.  But +1 for citing my favorite section of the FAQ.

Answer (score 13):

You [can't assign anything to an array variable in C](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/arraylval.html).  It's not a 'modifiable lvalue'.  From the spec, **§6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators**:

> An *lvalue* is an expression with an object type or an incomplete type other than **`void`**; if an lvalue does not designate an object when it is evaluated, the behavior is undefined. When an object is said to have a particular type, the type is specified by the lvalue used to designate the object. A *modifiable lvalue* is an lvalue that does not have array type, does not have an incomplete type, does not have a const-qualified type, and if it is a structure or union, does not have any member (including, recursively, any member or element of all contained aggregates or unions) with a const-qualified type.

The error message you're getting is a bit confusing because the array on the right hand side of the expression decays into a pointer before the assignment.  What you have is semantically equivalent to:

```
message1 = &message2[0];
```

Which gives the right side type `char *`, but since you still can't assign anything to `message1` (it's an array, type `char[100]`), you're getting the compiler error that you see.  You can solve your problem by using [`memcpy(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/memcpy):

```
memcpy(message1, message2, sizeof message2);
```

If you really have your heart set on using `=` for some reason, you could use use arrays inside structures... that's not really a recommended way to go, though.