# Compiler warning when char * set to string literal

Tags: c, char, constants

In my code I have

```
char* s = strchr(first,'/');
if(s==NULL) s = "";
else s = s+1;
```

But my gcc compiler complains at the penultimate line with

```
warning: assignment discards qualifiers from pointer target type
```

From what I understand about ANSI C, it is because I am setting s (a non-const value) to a string literal (a const value). (Am I wrong here?) Yet I need s to be non-const (because I may be changing its value by adding 1 to it), and I also need to set s to an empty string literal. Do I have any options in terms of better code design here to achieve these two objectives without the compiler yelling?

I do have the -Wwrite-strings flag enabled.

Comment: It's really hard to say. How about some more code? What are you trying to do? Do you just want to point it somewhere else or do you want to modify the string returned by strchr?

Comment: What modifications are you planning to make to the empty string?

Comment: 'Yet I need s to be non-const'  why ?

Comment: @Chris: See the edits I made above to have a look at why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `strcpy` instead of assigning string literals. The problem is that the string literal is constant, and `s` will contain the address of that string, not the string itself, which is bad.

For example if you have:

```
char str[100];
str = "Hello world";
```

The address of the 100 char's allocated will be replaced with the address of `"Hello world"` constant string.

Easiest way to make a string empty is to set the first value to NULL (`*s = NULL`);

Comment: You cannot assign a string literal to an array. `char str[100] = "Hello world";` is fine, but `char str[100]; str = "Hello world";` is not.

Comment: @KennyTM That's what I was trying to explain, it isn't correct because you are trying to assign the str pointer a different address

Comment: It isn't about the address, but incompatible types. A pointer cannot be assigned to an array.

Comment: In c/c++ arrays and pointers are very similar... I mean, you can call a function which has an int* parameter, and you give it an array, and you can access the n'th item after the address in the pointer using [] operator. However, compilers may have protection, to prevent changing the address.

Comment: An array may be decayed to a pointer, but not the reverse. And, [you cannot assign anything to an array](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7548463/224671). The `[]` operator is irrelevant, and BTW you can use `1["hi"]`, but that doesn't mean an `int` is similar to a pointer.

Comment: That's not what I'm saying. For example, you have int* a; you are allowed to use a[20] (of course, you have to allocate the memory before doing that). I did some research, and I learned that arrays are in fact const pointers, that is why you cannot change them.

Comment: An array is not a `const` pointer. The `sizeof` of array has different semantic than a `const` pointer. The `&` of array has different semantic than a `const` pointer. etc.

Comment: Arrays and pointers are not at all similar.  Read section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://c-faq.com).

Answer (score 3):

If you mean to write:

```
char * s = "Red";
if (Massachusetts) {
   s = "Blue";
}
```

then just add the const. It will work fine.

If you really need to *modify the string*, then

```
char *s = malloc(64);
strcpy (s, "Red");
if (Massachusetts) {
    strcat(s, "-not");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you need `s` to not be `const`, or do you need `s` to not address constant storage?  There's a big difference.  In the former case you can simply cast to `char*`.  In the latter case you must malloc the storage you need (or assign `s` with the address of a `char[]` value of appropriate scope).

Answer (score 1):

If you're not going to modify the object pointed to by `s`, change the type of `s` to `const char *s;`.

If you are going to modify it, then pointing it at a string whose contents are illegal to modify (whether that's illegal per the C language, or just by the contracts of the rest of your program's interfaces) is a serious bug, and you need to make sure you make a copy of the string whenever there's a possibility you might modify it.