# Incompatible types when assigning string to char array

Tags: c, arrays, char

so this is basically what i have atm. (This is for C)

```
char score[50];

if (num == 0){
    score = "draw";
    }
else if (num == 1){ 
    score = "100";
    }
else if (num == 2){
    score = "200";
    }
```

But i keep getting the error, incompatible types when assigning to type char [50] from type int. How do i fix this error?

Comment: The error message doesn't match the code shown.

Comment: Use `strncpy` E.g. `strncpy ( score, "draw", sizeof(score) );`

Comment: "*... from type int*" are you showing us the real code? I doubt it: -1

Comment: I tend to close this question as from the source shown it looks like being duplicate to: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7548408/694576

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [strcpy](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strcpy.htm):
`char *strcpy(char *dest, const char *src)`

```
#include <string.h>    //include the library containing the function strcpy

if (num == 0){
    strcpy(score, "draw");
}
else if (num == 1){ 
   strcpy(score, "100");
}
else if (num == 2){
    strcpy(score, "200");
}
```

Comment: k sweet ty. I just have another issue that came up. It says: 'implicit declaration of function 'strcopy''. (i have string.h)

Comment: It is strcpy not strcopy.

Comment: Look again at the name of the function that copies a C string.

Comment: You should use a pointer. Strcpy, in this case, is just going copy memory out of .rodata to your local variable. It is a waist of process time and of memory.

Answer (score 1):

Change your type to const char*

```
const char* score;

if (num == 0){
    score = "draw";
}
else if (num == 1){ 
    score = "100";
}
else if (num == 2){
    score = "200";
}
```

Comment: should be `const char* score;`

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to assign data to array...We can assign data as individual.Here to move string to array,use `strcpy` function,like follows

```
  char score[50];

   if (num == 0){
   strcpy(score,"draw");
   }
   else if (num == 1){ 
   strcpy(score,"100");
   }
   else if (num == 2){
   strcpy(score,"200");
   }
```

It is not possible to copy directly into array...